# Retrieving value from nested JSON object using jQuery .ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, typeerror

Let's say I have a JSON object returned from a different domain as follows (This originally contains fairly big volume of data so I omitted the irrelevant parts while keeping its structure intact):

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2013-10-08T21:06:49Z",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "results": {
            "quote": {
                "symbol": "GOOG",
                "Ask": "854.63",
                "AverageDailyVolume": "1837530",
                "PreviousClose": "865.74"
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Although I feel fairly comfortable working with JSON, I'm only beginning to learn the nuts and bolts of the jQuery .ajax function for interacting with JSON. I wrote very basic bits of code (below) just to ensure I can retrieve the JSON object and extract one or more values from it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('" + source + "') &format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://Fdatatables.org/alltables.env&callback=?",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.query.results.quote.symbol); // expected output is "GOOG"
    }
});
```

When I run above code in Firefox, I get `TypeError: data.query is undefined` error in the browser console. I noticed that there are several questions already posted that are similar to what I am asking here but haven't found anything that sufficiently addresses this issue - at least from my understanding.

Any advice/tips will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `console.log(data, typeof data);` to ensure you are actually getting a response?

Comment: "No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quotes" error i see.

Comment: Use the yahoo API console to test your YQL first that same error is returned directly from the yahoo API console for `select * from yahho.finance.quotes` http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.quotes

Comment: @James - I ran my YQL in the Yahoo API console successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is with the environment. `Fdatatables.org` is not a valid environment.

Change

```
env=http://Fdatatables.org/alltables.env&callback=?
```

to

```
env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&callback=?
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PZnZN/)**

Comment: This was it! I must've missed the 'F' character when I converted all URL-encoded characters. Another set of fresh eyes never hurts, does it? :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
success: function(data) {
        console.log($.parseJSON(data).query.results.quote.symbol); 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL to this:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?
    q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in
    ('GOOG')
    &format=json
    &diagnostics=true
    &env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env
```

I've tried to make it clear for the sake of formatting. Actual URL is

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20('GOOG')%20&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env